# When page unload, a confirm box appear I don't want

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a chat program like this:http://www.webengine.co.kr/wechat?l=en(korean site) and I have a problem like title.
(This problem appears sometimes. If you want test this, refresh the page many times.)

I think this problem was made by my ajax script

```
function wechat(id, chatroom_srl, last_chatline_srl, key, nick_name){
  this.id = id;
  this.chatroom_srl = chatroom_srl;
  this.last_chatline_srl = last_chatline_srl;
  this.key = key;
  this.nick_name = nick_name;
  this.wechat = $("#"+this.id);

  var oWechat = this.wechat;
  function exec_json_nomsg(a,b,c){
    if("undefined" == typeof b) b = {};
    a = a.split(".");
    if(2 == a.length){
      $.extend(b, {module:a[0],act:a[1]});
      if("undefined" != typeof xeVid) $.extend(b, {vid:xeVid});
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        url:request_uri,
        contentType:"application/json",
        data:$.param(b),
          success:function(a){
          if($.isFunction(c)) c(a);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  function procChatLines(data){
    for(i=0;i<data.chatline_list.length;i++){
      appendLine(data.chatline_list[i].nick_name, data.chatline_list[i].content, data.chatline_list[i].key);
      wechat.last_chatline_srl = data.chatline_list[i].chatline_srl;
    }
    wechat.timer = setTimeout(loadChatContents, 100);
  }
  function loadChatContents(){
    exec_json_nomsg("chat.loadChatContents", {chatroom_srl:wechat.chatroom_srl, last_chatline_srl:wechat.last_chatline_srl, key:wechat.key}, procChatLines);
    clearTimeout(wechat.timer);
  }
  function appendLine(nick_name, content, key){
    var lineObj = $("<div class=\"chatLine\"></div>");      
    if(wechat.key == key) lineObj.addClass("chatMe");       
    lineObj.html("<span class=\"chatNickBold\">"+nick_name+" : </span>"+content);
    oWechat.find(".chatContentHeight").append(lineObj);
    scrollDown();
  }
  function scrollDown(){
    var o = oWechat.find(".chatContent");
    o.stop().animate({scrollTop:o.find(">.chatContentHeight").height()-o.height()}, 300, "easeInOutQuart");
  }
  $(window).load(function(){
    scrollDown();
  });   
  oWechat.find(".wechatInput").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
      if($(this).val().trim() != ""){
        exec_json_nomsg("chat.procChatInsertChatLine",{"chatroom_srl":wechat.chatroom_srl,"content":$(this).val()});
        appendLine(wechat.nick_name, $(this).val(), wechat.key);
        $(this).val("");
      }
    }
  });
  wechat.timer = setTimeout(loadChatContents, 100);
}
  new wechat("wechat1", 1, [last_chatline_srl(PHP give this)], "[User Hidden Key(PHP give this)]", "[User Nick Name]");
```

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: There's nothing on the code you've posted that could lead to a problem like you're mentioning on the question title.

Comment: May be..try cmmenting `//alert(b.message);` or comment `//call_back_function();`. Don't know otherwise what you exactly want!

Comment: @MelanciaUK This problem appears sometimes. If you want test this, press F5 key many times.

Comment: @VarunMalhotra call_back_function must exists and I did alreay what deleting alert function.

Comment: I resolve this problem myself.
Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your syntax is just a bit wrong. You are missing an extra bracket. This is what it should look like.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    url:request_uri,
    contentType:"application/json",
    data:postData,
    success:function(b){
        if(0 < b.error){
            //we get to here if b.error is < 0. 
            alert(b.message);
        }
        else{
            call_back_function();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: what happens when you do a console.log(b) before the if statement inside the success function? What is b? Maybe you are getting errors back?

Comment: It resolve not my problem.
Just My mistake in editing to I writing here.

Comment: ok well if you want us to help fix your problem, you need to post the entire problem, not just one part of it. I've fixed the mistake you made in what you posted, but I need to see more code to be able to help further. When I went to the website you gave, I see that all the errors are 0. And I never got an alert popping up. So I don't see a problem.

Comment: Access here:http://www.webengine.co.kr/wechat?l=en and you can see it in console.(and I didn't get error)

Comment: If you want to see the problem, You just refresh the page many times.(This problem appears sometimes). And I will post more the code here.

Comment: I think I know what you mean! It's not that you are getting the alert in your code! The problem you are getting is when you refresh the page, it asks if you want to reload it right? It has nothing to do with the code you put up. That happens because you have a form somewhere and it feels like you have submitted it, so it wants to see if you want to resubmit the form

Comment: Then.. How can I resolve this problem? In the chat program, Don't exists <form>. <from> tag just in login box, and search box, and layer popup chating box. but, other pages didn't happen the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure. It might be a residue from the login page or more likely from the search box. However, that is a complicated problem that would require me to look through your entire code set

Comment: But... When I deleted the ajax code($.ajax({~~~});), this problem isn't appeared.
I think that the confirm box appear because page unload when ajax is processing

Answer (score 0):

your problem is not in the script you have sent, on the website that you have pointed to you are using a widget on the srchat.js file line 648 and 649 you have:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){if(!chtisbk && chtunload == 'Y') {if(dallar('cht_gout').value == '0'){if(cht_go('out')){dallar('cht_gout').value = '9';if(navigator.appName == 'Opera') alert('접속을 종료합니다');}}}}
window.onunload = function(){window.onbeforeunload();}
```

those two lines are responsible for that message.

you also are using this libary common/js/xe.min.js
on this libary when an ajax call is initiated it will display that message until the call returned a value. if you want to modify that you need the source of that file.

Comment: But, the confirm box doesn't appear in other pages

Comment: it will only appear when you have an ajax call,  I am pretty sure that the xe.min.js is the one responsible, that's why you don't get the message when you delete the ajax call from your code.